# Why android NDK application crashes if i export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Basic Question in android. I wrote hello world cpp file, and used ndk-build to compile, and created executable. It works perfectly fine. Then i linked one shared library in Android.mk like:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mysimplelibrary
```

and now, i created a executable, and pushed into the device, when i run the executable in the device,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./sample
```

i get the error:

```
[1] + Stopped (signal)          ./sample
```

What am i doing wrong? What sort of changes i need to consider while linking with SHARED LIBRARY?

Answer (score 0):

If they are both shared libraries you need to call loadlibrary on both of them in your app.

Comment: In your Android app.  You should be calling `System.load("libMyLibrary");` somewhere and you just need to call it for both *.so files.

Comment: I m tring to execute the binary into shell prompt of the device, and i am not using android app.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the NDK docs/SYSTEM-ISSUES.html file:

> - No support for LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD, RTLD_LOCAL and many   other options.

That's why it crashes.